# How to extract numbers from duplicates and text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data as below:

```
23
23
23
23
23
False
False
False
False
False
10
10
10
10
10
False
False
False
False
False
False
30
30
30
30
30
30
False
False
...
```

Which formula can I use to only select the number such as to another column:

```
23
10
30
..
```

Comment: Are those entries the Boolean FALSE or the text string "False"? If you're not sure, the formula =0+A1 will return 0 if the entry in A1 is a Boolean FALSE and #VALUE! if it is actually the text string "False".

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try a filtering option. I believe your answer lies within this  [link](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-d6549cf0-357a-4acf-9df5-ca507915b704)